# Left Trim in Linq

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

How to use left trim in linq?

```
return View(s.OrderBy(e => e.MoleculeName).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

I need to trim the space at the beginning of molecule name. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean in the `OrderBy` call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use [`String.TrimStart()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart(v=vs.110).aspx) to strim the space at the left of the string. Since Strings are immutable, the original string will not change, but you will `OrderBy` the trimmed string.

```
return View(s.OrderBy(e => e.MoleculeName.TrimStart())
                            .ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the below

```
return View(s.OrderBy(e => e.MoleculeName.TrimStart()).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

- `TrimStart()` - will remove the extra white space at the beginning of the string.
- `TrimEnd()` - will remove the extra white space at the end of the string.
- `Trim()` - will remove the extra white space both at the beginning and end of the string.